# Can iPhone web apps get GPS position?

Tags: iphone, iphone-web-app

Can iPhone web apps request and get the GPS position or do you need to use full-blown apps for this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058880 for better answers. This question is a dupe and should be flagged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can iPhone web apps get GPS position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058880/can-iphone-web-apps-get-gps-position)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can access it via Javascript.

It's called GeoLocation and it's supported from firmware 3.0.
You can see an example [here](http://blog.bemoko.com/2009/06/17/iphone-30-geolocation-javascript-api/).

Answer (score 1):

Google Latitude seems to be able to access the GPS from a web app.

http://www.google.com/latitude/intro.html